# Перевод текста в одну строку

Tags: java

Код программы считывает информацию из файла и переводит его в строку:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Reader reader = new FileReader(args[0]);
    String buf = "";
    while (reader.ready())
    {
        int data = reader.read();
        buf = buf + (char)data;
    }
    buf = buf.replace('\n', ' ');
```

Проблема в последней строке. Без нее переменная `buf` отображает текст файла адекватно.

Текст файла:

```
Petrov 2.7
Sidorov 3.15
Petrov 5
Varez 3.1
Kirk 9
```

Переменная `buf` без метода `replace` выводит в консоль:

```
Petrov 2.7
Sidorov 3.15
Petrov 5
Varez 3.1
Kirk 9
```

Если я добавляю `replace`, то вместо замены символа `'\n'` (переход на другую строку) на `' '` (пробел) и итогового текста в одну строку я получаю только последний элемент с символом `' '` перед ним.

Вывод в консоль после `buf = buf.replace('\n', ' ')`:

```
 Kirk 9
```

В чем нарушена логика выполнения и как ее можно исправить, чтобы текст выводился в виде

```
Petrov 2.7 Sidorov 3.15 Petrov 5 Varez 3.1 Kirk 9
```

Использовать по условию могу только `FileReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в файле у вас не просто `\n`, а `\r\n`. Поэтому при замене только `\n` все `\r` остаются на месте, что приводит к выводу символов после `\r` с начала строки с затиранием уже выведенных символов.

То есть в `buf` по-прежнему хранятся все строки (в этом можно убедиться с помощью `System.out.println(buf.length())`), однако выводится `buf` некорректно (относительно того как нужно вам).

В данном случае достаточно сделать так:

```
buf = buf.replace("\r\n", " ");
```

В общем случае (если неизвестно как сделаны переводы строк в файле) стоит учитывать оба варианта (`\r\n` и `\n`):

```
buf = buf.replaceAll("\r\n|\n", " ");
```

---

А ещё я бы переписал код с закрытием `Reader`-а после чтения, обработкой исключений в самом коде, блочным чтением данных и использованием `StringBuilder` вместо конкатенации строк:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String fileName = args[0];
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(fileName))
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[1024];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int readCount;
        while ((readCount = reader.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            sb.append(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
        String result = sb.toString().replace("\r\n", " ");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: В идеале брать разделитель строк системный и пользоваться уже им: `String separator = System.lineSeparator();` Ибо платформонезависимость!

Comment: Не совсем. Правильнее исключать \r (13 байт) это только в винде принето, сувать куда попало 13 очистка каретки. Но как известно java кросс..

Comment: @ДенисКотляров в общем случае правильнее заменять и `\r\n`, и `\n` и не смотреть при этом на используемую ОС. Добавил этот вариант в ответ, дабы закончить таки эту дискуссию. И не стоит столько негативно относиться к `\r`.